# Is it true that the Prophets and Allah hate and don't care for this dunya?

Tags: allah, prophets

I was feeling depressed and I heard that Allah couldn't care less of this dunya because Adam (S) was sent here as punishment.

Is it true that humans can never be happy here no matter what Allah gives because this place was designed to break your heart.

I heard a hadith about a dead goats head has the low value of dunya or something like that.

Is it also true that the bigger the test the better reward and that there is a hadith that people will wish they had a bad life because of Allah rewards. Right?

Comment: This nice query can be deemed as a constructive basis question which could be helpful for us in order not to be so dependent to it ... Hope to see appropriate answers as 2 dear users presented ... nicely ...

Answer (score 2):

Of course Allah swt cares for dunya. He has created dunya for us and provided everything we need in dunya in the most perfect way. However, dunya is just a temporary place and not our final destination.

Therefore we must not attach our heart to dunya as this is the place of struggle, testing, calamity, illness, death, hunger, thirst and desperation. Of course there are many positive things in dunya as well but everything in dunya is not lasting.

So compared to the next life in the Hereafter, which is the real life, were there is no death and where a believer is rewarded for his deeds with eternal bliss, inshallah, dunya is a bad place.

> The Prophet said: Verily Allah revealed to the world, 'Tire and wear out the one who serves you, and serve the one who rejects you.'[Amali al-Saduq, p.230, no.9]

Thus, it is a good place when we use it for self-development, learning and helping others and do not strive for its pleasures and be occupied by accumulating wealth or gaining power but be always aware that we must leave this world sooner or later.

> The one who attaches his heart to the world has attached his heart to three things: endless worry, false expectations and unattainable hope.[Imam al-Sadiq, al-Kafi, 2, p.320, no. 17]

We must Ask ourselves the question whether we have used our wordly life to gain in the Hereafter or have we wasted the time which was given to us and lose.

The bigger the trial, the bigger the reward - that's only fair. The one who put more effort into something, spent more time and energy, sometimes even his life, needs to be rewarded more than the one who did less in all of this.

But this does not mean that we should be sad when our life is not full of difficulties and misery all the time. Everybody has a different ability and capacity to cope with calamities and bad times, therefore Allah swt tests each of us differently, according to our ability because He does not want to break us but He does want us to develop in His direction. And even good times or a lot of money and success can be a test. Do you become arrogant or greedy because of your wealth or good job position or do you share your money with the less fortunate and help your colleagues to succeed as well.

The most important thing to remember is, that we must always thank Allah for what He has given us, no matter good or bad.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is totally wrong. Look if Allah does not love us then why He always forgive us?U know Allah had made us a Muslim because he want to see us in Jannah. We just have to prove that we r worthy of it. Look Allah loves us that is,the prove I have given u.And the answer 4 the dunya is that it is temporary.We humans r not designed 4 dunya indeed we r designed 4 Jannah.U know this is our exam. Allah takes our test and judge us by two ways.When a blessing is given to us or when any clamity strikes on us.Allah loves us. Allah do care 4 us. See a mother,one mother care 4 us and u tell me what about Allah. He loves us more than 70 mothers. Any idea?
And stop saying anything wrong about Allah. The best technique is keep on reciting kalima and read the Quran with Translation and Tafseer. That's all I can advice u!Jazak Allah!And yes ask Allah 4 guidance.